# 解答例のコードがどのように動くのかわかりません

Tags: c

書籍「すっきりわかるC言語入門」の練習問題の解答例について質問です。

要素３のint型配列 answer の各要素に０〜９のランダムな1桁の数を重複しないように格納するコードの解答例です。
bool型で check を定義した後の check = false; が何を意味しているのかが理解できません。
変数　check に false を代入しただけで for(answer[i] == answer[j]) がどうして実行されるようになるのでしょうか。

```
int answer[3];
int input[3];
bool check;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    do{
        answer[i] = rand()% 10;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            check = false;
            if(answer[i] == answer[j]){
                break;
            }
            check = true;
        }
    }while (i > 0 && check == false);
}
```

Comment: プログラムの動きを理解したいということであれば、デバッガーを用いてステップ操作で一行ずつ実行して変数や比較文がどういう動きになるか見てみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに1行ずつ実行して、どのような挙動になるのか確かめてみるのもいいですね、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do-whileや計算を少なくする工夫に富んでいますが、変則的で欲張りな解答例ですね。
下記にコメントをつけておきました。

```c
int answer[3]; //要素は全て0となる前提
int input[3];
bool check;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    do
    {
        // ランダムな数を生成
        answer[i] = rand()% 10;

        // 今までの数を確認する
        // iが2なら、jは0と1を確認)
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            //ここで未チェック(初期状態)とする
            check = false;

            //もし重複があったらanswer[i]を作り直すためにforループを抜ける
            //このときdo-whileは抜けないので、iは変わらない
            if(answer[i] == answer[j])
            {
                break;
            }
            // ここでチェック済みとする
            // whileの条件を満たさないためdo-whileを抜けて次のiのforループから続ける
            check = true;
        }
    }while (i > 0 && check == false);// ここでループ条件を設定して確認(checkがtrueになるまで繰り返す)
}
```

Comment: 要するに、最下行の i > 0 && check == false を条件付けするために bool型を定義したということですね。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、特定の条件を使ってループを止めるために、定義していると思います。近年はbool値を扱う場合、isXXX及び is_xxxといった形式で宣言します。ご参考までに。

Comment: なるほど。少し理解できた気がします。ありがとうございます！